# Reack Data picker useState

Tags: css, reactjs, web, frontend, backend

I try to use Reack Data picker on my react project from [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) 
but cant Import **useState** from `import React, { useState } from "react";`

> the error is : 'useState' is declared but its value is never read.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can and already did. What the error says is basically that you have imported `useState`, but to have any value from it - please use it. The error is there so that if you don't forget to remove things if you do not need them.

Comment: First Thank you , I have attached error photo , it is error and I don't no how to solve it

Comment: What is the version of react you are using? It might be an old one, since hooks became available since the 16.8